# Is it possible to deploy separate azure roles to different services when publishing via Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-web-roles

I have an azure project with two different web roles.  I would like the different roles to be deployed to different services, not the same service.  Is this possible, or do I need to create a separate azure project in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate cloud service project.  Although there might be a better way to accomplish your ultimate goal if you want to share more details about what you are trying to do.  For example, you can host multiple sites within the same WebRole and use host headers to differentiate the traffic.  This limits your scalability options (ie. you can't scale Website1 independently of Website2), but it can reduce costs if the load on the sites is low.